# Unable to SaveAs MailItem as msg file using third party application

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have vsto Addon for outlook. In my addon, there is a functionality to save mail items locally. This functionality is worked in the background automatically. To implement this functionality, I have developed one background application. In this application, I will save the email in a decided folder. This add-on works fine for my computer but in some of client-facing an issue while saving email. As per the log files, I have checked when I tried to save email this error is generated.

Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))

Before publishing this blog, I have tried to get a fresh mail item using Outlook. Application object but still the issue is not fixed.

Can anyone please help us to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Object Model cannot be used from a secondary thread in the outlook.exe process address space. You can use it from a secondary thread in an external process, but then the call will be marshaled to the main Outlook thread anyway. There is no marshaling in-proc, hence you get an error.

Your options are Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (can be used in any language - I am its author). In the latter case, you can save the value of the `Namespace.MAPIOBJECT` and `MailItem.EntryID` properties in separate variables on the main thread, and on the secondary thread create an instance of the [RDOSession](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) object, set its `MAPIOBJECT` property to the value saved on the main thread, open then message using `RDOSession.GetMessageFromID`, then call [RDOMail](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).`SaveAs(..., olMsg)`.